# не переведено определение выдержки из описания метки

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

На странице редактирования любой метки присутствует английский текст:

> The usage guidance, or tag wiki excerpt, is a short blurb that
>   describes when and why a tag should be used on this site specifically.

Comment: Исправил, применил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Руководство по использованию или краткое описание метки — сжатая инструкция по тому, как и когда следует её использовать на этом сайте.

Comment: Что-то все время масло масляное получается..

Comment: Тогда можно чуть изменить: `Руководство по использованию или краткое описание метки — сжатая инструкция по тому как и почему ее следует использовать.`

Comment: Слово blurb подразумевает рекламу/агитацию, поэтому "агитка" больше подходит чем "инструкция". Представьте себе что ходят злые люди и  выжигают все метки, которые свою полезность не убедительно рекламируют.

Comment: @jfs: у меня слово «агитка» ассоциируется с пропагандой и политикой.

Comment: @avp: спасибо, взял ваш вариант.

Answer (score -2):

Буквальный перевод:

> Руководство по использованию или краткое описание метки—краткая
>   агитка, которая описывает когда и почему метка должна быть
>   использована именно на данном сайте.

Answer (score -2):

> Руководство по использованию или краткое описание метки—краткая
>   агитка, которая описывает когда и почему метка должна быть
>   использована на сайте.

Super User, Server Fault, etc на русском не существуют поэтому можно "именно" и на "данном" слова пропустить.