# Полупрозрачность не исчезает

Tags: дефект

Когда рейтинг ответа меняется с -3 на -2, ответ остаётся полупрозрачным. Приходится обновлять страницу.

When votes change from -3 to -2 the answer stands semitransparent. Need to reload the page to get it right.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: А в обратную сторону работает?

Comment: @alexolut, вроде работало раньше. Но гарантировать не могу. Можешь попробовать проверить на каком-нибудь `is:a votes:-2..-2` (у меня сегодняшний лимит голосов закончился).

Comment: @alexolut, работает

Comment: @Yuri у меня наоборот, в плюс работает, а в минус нет. А вот [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1113/176217) при голосовании в минус затуманивает совсем другой ответ: делаем один (-3), обновляем страницу, откатываем до (-2), оно светлеет, делаем (-3) на другом, затуманивается то, которое (-2).

Comment: @alexolut, у меня теперь ни то, ни другое. Только обновлять страницу нужно

Comment: @Yuri каждый день что-то новое!